# Use SegmentController to Make TableView Disappear and UIContainerView Appear

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to use a segment controller to switch between my tableView and a container view, but when I try to switch between them it only half works. The TableView appears and disappears, but the container view never appears.

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func switchAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        profileTableView.isHidden = false
        modelsContainerView.isHidden = true
    } else {
        profileTableView.isHidden = true
        modelsContainerView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If i use this code the simulation sort of works. The container view appears but it doesn't fill the screen like the tableview did.

```
    @IBAction func switchAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.profileTableView.alpha = 1
            self.modelsContainerView.alpha = 0
        })
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.profileTableView.alpha = 0
            self.modelsContainerView.alpha = 1
        })
    }
}
```

[image: Updated picture]

I can tell it's not working because I've set the container view's background color to pink. And this is what it looks like when I try to switch from TableView(which works) to container View:
[image: Segment With TableView]

[image: Segment Where Container View Should Appear (not working)]

[image: Storyboard]

All of the outlets appear to be connected. And my UI set up is a green view behind the segment controller, with a tableView below and a containerView that in the same place.

Thank you very much for your help in advanced.

Comment: can you make a screenshot of the view hierarchy in the storyboard?

Comment: It's been uploaded. @LoryHuz

Comment: which view has the green background exactly ? it's not clear in your post

Comment: I've tried to place a green background view behind the segment controller. But when the segment controller switches to models it seems to have grown in size

Comment: When I try this it sort of works. `    @IBAction func switchAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.profileTableView.alpha = 1
                self.modelsContainerView.alpha = 0
            })
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.profileTableView.alpha = 0
                self.modelsContainerView.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    }
` Except the new container view only fills a little

Comment: I want to know where is the green view on your hierarchy, I understand it's behind but it's not enough to help

Comment: Looks like your `Segment Background` view does not have a height constraint, so when you hide the `Profile Table View` `Segment Background` expands vertically, and is covering your `Models Container View`

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry. What do you mean by on your hierarchy?

Comment: @DonMag The height is set to 45

Comment: And... is there a reason you are using the Container View in that manner? In general, you would have your segmented control at the top of the view, then a ContainerView below it... and you would swap your Table View and your Models View *within* that container view.

Comment: The three on the left in your screen "View > StackView > Segment Background", etc. Which one is green ? We didn't see

Comment: I'm also betting your Stack View is set to Fill, so no matter what height you set the Segment Background to, it will be expanded by the Stack View

Comment: No reason in particular just that I was having trouble with the other option you suggested.

Comment: @LoryHuz Segment background is green

Comment: @DonMag it is set to fill. What should it be instead?

Comment: OK - then I'd suggest you revisit Container Views and how they work. That should give you a much better view hierarchy, and is kinda one of the purposes of using a Container View to begin with.

Comment: Segment background is in front of your container and you hide ONLY the tableview, so it's logic you have issues to see your container

Comment: @BenNalle - take a read through this article - it may be a little out-of-date, but it presents pretty much exactly what you are trying to do here. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/09/02/switch-container-views/

Comment: @DonMag I was giving that a try but I couldn't figure out how to place the container views on top of each other while they were in a stack view any suggestions?

Comment: No real reason to use a stack view... constrain your segment background view to the top, constrain the Container View to the bottom of the segment background and to the bottom of the view. Constrain the "contained views" to the 4 sides of the container view.

Comment: @DonMag any reason you know of that would explain why following the instruction in the link you provided would set off an error about unwrapping an optional? All I did was add container views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach...

[image]

Seg Background view is 45-pts height, and pinned top, leading, trailing all equal to `0`.

Profile Container is pinned leading, trailing, bottom all equal to `0`, and the top is pinned to the bottom of Seg Background.

But you can't see Profile Container (red background), because Models Container (orange background) is on top of it, and...

Models Container is equal width and height, and centered Horizontally and Vertically, all to Profile Container.

Profile Container has Profile Table VC embedded in it.

Models Container has Models VC embedded in it.

The idea is:

When `Seg 0` is selected, Profile Container is alpha 1 and **not** hidden, while Models Container is alpha 0 and **is** hidden.

When `Seg 1` is selected, Profile Container is alpha 0 and **is** hidden, while Models Container is alpha 1 and **not** hidden.

```
class SegContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileContainerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var modelsContainerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // start with Profile visible
        // so hide Models and set its alphs to 0
        self.modelsContainerView.alpha = 0
        self.modelsContainerView.isHidden = true

    }

    @IBAction func switchAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        // on segment select, the "other" container will be
        // transparent and hidden, so
        // un-hide it, then animate the alpha for both (for cross-fade)
        // on animation completion, hide the now transparent container

        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

            self.profileContainerView.isHidden = false
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

                self.profileContainerView.alpha = 1
                self.modelsContainerView.alpha = 0

            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in

                self.modelsContainerView.isHidden = true

            })

        } else {

            self.modelsContainerView.isHidden = false
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

                self.profileContainerView.alpha = 0
                self.modelsContainerView.alpha = 1

            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in

                self.profileContainerView.isHidden = true

            })

        }

    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

To access the Embedded View Controllers, override prepareForSegue:

```
var theProfileVC: ProfileTableViewController?
var theModelsVC: ModelsViewControler?

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let vc = segue.destination as? ProfileTableViewController {

        // do something here if desired, like setting a property of the VC

        // save a reference so we can use it later
        theProfileVC = vc
    }

    if let vc = segue.destination as? ModelsViewControler {

        // do something here if desired, like setting a property of the VC

        // save a reference so we can use it later
        theModelsVC = vc

    }

}
```

I've also updated the GitHub repo with an example of this.

---

I put this up as a sample project, if you'd like to dig into it: https://github.com/DonMag/SegmentsAndContainers

Comment: Hi @DonMag I am trying to access a property from the ViewController that contains the container views from within the ViewController that backs one of the container views, but I am struggling to do so. Do you have any suggestions? It appears that the container view loads before the ViewController containing the container view loads and as a result I can access the property but the property hasn't been set yet.

Comment: hmmm... you have "MainVC" that holds your switch and two container views... you want code in MainVC to set a property in one (or both) of the VCs embedded in the Container Views?

Comment: A property in just one of the VCs embedded in the container view

Comment: but the MainVC loads after the VC in the container view so the property isn't available to be used

Comment: In MainVC, create a variable for the VC you want to "communicate with" (I'll assume it's ModelsVC for the moment). When the container view loads its embedded VC, it triggers **prepare for segue**. In MainVC, `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` .. where you can check if it's the ModelsVC or not... if it *is*, then assign it to your variable. After that, you can reference it and its properties / funcs / methods / etc.

Comment: @BenNalle - see my edits, and the updated GitHub project

Comment: Ok I tried to implement what you've suggested but I've done something wrong. I added a variable to the VC that holds the container view like this `var profileVC = UIViewController()` and then my `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` looks like this: `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier != "showProfileContainerView" { return }
        
        profileVC = ProfileViewController
        
    }` but that sets off an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158631/discussion-between-donmag-and-ben-nalle).