# Segemented Control Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I was wondering how you use segmented control in a navigation controller. I want it so that on one of the screens, when they click the segmented control, they can flip between 2 other pages (hence 3 all together).

When I try doing this in a navigation controller, they either don't have any navigation bars (once a segue is made from each view controller to each of the other 2 (6 in total)), or if I connect them in series then they all have back buttons.

How would I achieve the segmented control effect to flip between 3 pages in a navigation controller, each with the same back button (i.e. it goes back to the same page), without running into any of the problems mentioned above?

Thanks in advance. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use SegmentController to Make TableView Disappear and UIContainerView Appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46961231/use-segmentcontroller-to-make-tableview-disappear-and-uicontainerview-appear)

Comment: Can you post a gif of what you are looking to achieve? (or possibly point to something similar in an app which is already out there)